# Why doesn't Marshal.Release call Release on my COM object?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

I've read the documentation for [`Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getiunknownforobject.aspx) and it says:

> Always use `Marshal.Release` to decrement the reference count once you have finished with the pointer.

I wrote a test solution with a COM object which I use via .NET and I see that when working with the [wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) to my COM object neither `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject` nor `Marshal.Release` cause the `AddRef` or `Release` methods of my COM object to be called.

What's up with that?

Comment: Could you provide sample code?

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject is for getting a punk to a *managed* object, so what is this "my COM object" that you are speaking of? It doesn't addref *your* COM object, it addref's *the runtime's managed object*. Can you explain in a whole lot more detail what it is you're trying to do here?

Comment: Updated the question to be clearer

Comment: @EricLippert, if `GetIUnknownForObject` reference counting pertains to the RCW, then why does the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getiunknownforobject(v=vs.110).aspx) say to call `Marshal.Release` as opposed to `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wait a minute, I think I've got it. You are making a COM object, then you are making a runtime callable wrapper around that COM object, and then you're asking the runtime callable wrapper for its punk, and then you're wondering why calling release on that punk doesn't call your Release?  Does that sum up your question?

If so, you might have mentioned all those details *in the question* rather than making us guess.

Well, why do you suppose it would it call *your* Release?  it's going to call the Release *of the runtime callable wrapper*. The wrapper *wraps* your object; that's why its called a *wrapper*. The runtime callable wrapper doesn't *need* to addref and release your object every time *it* is addref'd and released! Why would it? It needs to keep your object alive and *it already has a ref on your object*; that is sufficient to keep the wrapped object alive. Why do unnecessary work?

When you just have a runtime callable wrapper around a COM object you should reasonably expect to that the ref count on the object is unchanging for the entire lifetime of the object. The runtime takes a ref once, and when the RCW is garbage collected for the last time or released in some other manner, it releases that ref and the object deletes itself.

Think about it like this. Suppose you said:

```
foo->bar = blah;
blah->AddRef();
```

blah gets addref'd because foo->bar has a reference to it.  Now you say:

```
abc->def = foo;
foo->AddRef();
```

That adds a ref to foo. Does it add a ref to blah? Of course not. Why would it?  foo has a ref to blah; the fact that foo is being kept alive by abc is irrelevant to blah.

Same thing here. You have:

```
wrapper = new RCW();
wrapper->wrapped = yourobject;
yourobject->AddRef();
```

That adds a ref to yourobject. Now if you have

```
wrapper->QI(IUnknown, &punk)
```

that doesn't give you the punk to the underlying object, it gives you the punk of the wrapper. If you say

```
punk->AddRef();
```

that doesn't addref the underlying object, it addrefs the wrapper.

Comment: Sorry about the question not being descriptive enough, I'll update it.I knew that the RCW keeps a separate reference count (as seen in `ReleaseComObject` but for some reason I was under the impression that `Release` goes directly to the underlying COM object (in retrospect this is probably because the argument to `Release` is named `pUnk` in the documentation). Thanks for clearing things up.

Answer (score 3):

The `Marshal.AddRef` and `Marshal.Release` methods are calling the COM AddRef and Release methods of the COM instance; `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject` is likely to be calling [`QueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which implies an `AddRef` on the returned `IUnknown` pointer.

Maybe your test project is somehow buggy, possibly calling AddRef and Remove on another COM instance than the one you expect?

Comment: And `QueryInterface` is required (by the OLE rules) to increment the reference count.  It might do that by calling `AddRef`, but it could also do it by directly accessing its own internal member variables.

Comment: @Ben, that's why I wrote "implies". This is also how the documentation is describing it, because the effect has to be the same as for `AddRef`; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: did you ninja edit?  I don't think that wording was there when I commented, but I really like your answer now.

Comment: This is not the case, I get AddRef when the [RCW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) is created but not when I call `GetIUnknownForObject` on the RCW and no release when I call `Release` on the `IntPtr`.

Comment: Examining the [CLR source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/marshalnative.cpp), it seems that `SuppressRelease()` is used throughout the CLR to interfere with reference counting on the RCW. From what I can tell, the cases are sparse and haphazard enough to render deterministic management of RCWs via `ReleaseComObject` impractical.